# Not able to load crystal reports in visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, report

I want to use crystal reports for my windows forms application
I installed the msi file from official site
It was installed successfully and When i want to add new item the Crystal reports option is displayed but when it is loaded it shows me a link to download the crystal reports inside the VS2010 .
I have changed the.NET Profile to .NET profile from client version
But still no luck !
Thank you for help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnot install the Exe file but the MSI file
Silly one !

Answer (score 0):

Any Msi file is not sufficient for Crystal Reports for Visual Studio ,An executable file is also needed for it load in the VS10